# Why is Gmail returning a UID outside the range specified by UID FETCH command?

Tags: jakarta-mail, imap, gmail-imap

When I run a fetch command `UID FETCH 170930:170930 BODY[]` I get the response `88924 FETCH (UID 170920 FLAGS (\Seen))`. I wasn't expecting to retrieve a message with a UID out of the range specified. Is this normal IMAP behaviour? The 170930 UID came from watching the folder with an IdleManager only moments earlier, so I have no reason to believe that a message with that UID doesn't exist on the server.

The fetch request I've posted here is a guess based on the Java code I'm using to execute it. At the very least it should still be requesting only messages within that range:

```
Argument args = new Argument();
args.writeString(Long.toString(start) + ":" + Long.toString(end));
args.writeString("BODY[]");
Response[] r = protocol.command("UID FETCH", args);
Response response = r[r.length - 1];
```

Comment: Start: and end: aren't valid syntax.  I'm surprised this works at all.

Comment: I've updated the question, I'm actually issuing the request from some Java code so I'm guessing the raw output.

Comment: Can you turn on [JavaMail session debugging](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug) and post the debug output showing this?

Comment: Also, why are you using these low level internal JavaMail classes instead of the javax.mail classes?

Comment: Thanks Bill. I'll include the debugging and update the question with the output soon. I'm using the low level access as part of a custom ProtocolCommand to fetch the body of a large number of emails in a single request. In this example the range is for a single UID but in others I retrieve hundreds in a single fetch. AFAIK there's no way to specify a fetch profile in JavaMail that will retrieve the body for all included when using folder.fetch.

Answer (score 2):

An IMAP server is required to send you `FETCH` responses in certain cases. Sometimes the server is required to wait with responses, but it's never required *not* to send you any.

If you send a command that requires two response, and someone else does something that requires one response to you, then you get three responses. That something might be to change the flag on a message (requires `FETCH ... FLAGS ...` to you, although there's no promptness requirement) or send you some mail (requires `EXISTS` to you).